# Java: Rename Files - Not renaming files correctly

Tags: java, file-rename

The following Java code renames files but it does not rename the way I wanted it to. I want the rename files to start from beginning in the directory to the end per the “part” numbers (not the time it was added in inside a particular directory), but it does not do so. Is there an “if” check I can put, like: `if filename.contains(j)` then process this?

```
import java.io.File;

public class RenameFile2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String absolutePath1 = "1 to 4";
        String absolutePath2 = "6 to 9";
        String absolutePath3 = "10 to 99";
        String absolutePath4 = "100 to 224";

        File dir1 = new File(absolutePath1);
        File dir2 = new File(absolutePath2);
        File dir3 = new File(absolutePath3);
        File dir4 = new File(absolutePath4);

        File[] filesInDir1 = dir1.listFiles();
        File[] filesInDir2 = dir2.listFiles();
        File[] filesInDir3 = dir3.listFiles();
        File[] filesInDir4 = dir4.listFiles();

        int i1 = 1;

        for(File file:filesInDir1) {
            String name = file.getName();
            String newName = "550 00510 00" + i1 + ".pdf";
            String newPath = absolutePath1 + "\\" + newName;
            file.renameTo(new File(newPath));
            System.out.println(name + " changed to " + newName);
            i1++;
        }

        int i2 = 6;
        for(File file:filesInDir2) {
            String name = file.getName();
            String newName = "550 00510 00" + i2 + ".pdf";
            String newPath = absolutePath2 + "\\" + newName;
            file.renameTo(new File(newPath));
            System.out.println(name + " changed to " + newName);
            i2++;
        }

        int i3 = 10;
        for(File file:filesInDir3) {
            String name = file.getName();
            String newName = "550 00510 0" + i3 + ".pdf";
            String newPath = absolutePath3 + "\\" + newName;
            file.renameTo(new File(newPath));
            System.out.println(name + " changed to " + newName);
            i3++;
        }

        int i4 = 100;
        //int j = 99;
        for(File file:filesInDir4) {
            String name = file.getName();
/*            if(name.contains(j))
                {
                }
*/
            String newName = "550 00510 " + i4 + ".pdf";
            String newPath = absolutePath4 + "\\" + newName;
            file.renameTo(new File(newPath));
            System.out.println(name + " changed to " + newName);
            i4++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, you should extract a method for the "files processing". then the answer is probably to use some sorting on `filesInDirX` to get the order you want

Comment: `1 to 4` (and the others) is not an *absolute* path.

Comment: Check return value of `renameTo()`. Only print "renamed" if it returns true.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have resolved the problem with Arrays.Sort() as RP has mentioned below. I will check on the recommendations that you have given to see if the code can be made better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the files once you list them, the `listFiles()` does not guarentee any order.

```
File[] filesInDir1 = dir1.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(filesInDir1);
```

You may need to implement a `Comparator` and call `Arrays.sort(filesList, comparator)` in order to have them custom sorted.

Once you have the files in sorted order, you can apply the rename logic as you wanted.

Another improvement would be, if you want to list only files with a pattern, you can filter while listing.

```
final String pattern = "regexpattern";
 dir1.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
                           public boolean accept( File dir, String name ) {
                               return name.matches( pattern );
                           }
                        });
```

Comment: Thanks RP, I have used the Arrays.Sort that has resolved the file renaming problem. Still, I have to make the code better, as the sort that I’m using is kind of primitive and also I have changed the input source as numerical values instead of strings as these had before in the file name. I will check on comparator that you've mentioned to sort the files with any type of names. I have to read more about it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad that you found the way to solve the problem, if any of given solutions helped you in solving pls mark that as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation for `.listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--), it says:

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular, guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

You need to sort the array in the order you want to process them in a particular order.

---

Additional notes and suggestions:

- [`String.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) takes a `String` as an argument, not an `int`.  You have this code commented out in your question.
- Use the constructor for [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.io.File-java.lang.String-) to produce the new path instead of string concatenation:  `File newPath = new File(dir1, newName);`

Comment: Thanks dsh for your feedback. I will read up more on this and will try to make the code better. Thank you.